# Namespaces in Swift

Tags: swift, namespaces, name-clash, name-collision

I'm writing an extension to `String` to return a reversed version of it:

```
extension String{

    func rev()->String{
        var r = ""
        r.extend(reverse(self))
        return r
    }
}
```

The code works fine, but I'd like to call this method `reverse`, and not `rev`. If I do it, I get an error as the method name conflicts with the generic function `reverse`:

```
extension String{

    func reverse()->String{
        var r = ""
        r.extend(reverse(self)) // this is where I get the error
        return r
    }
}
```

Is there a way to specify that I mean the generic function `reverse` inside the body of the method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always call the Swift function explicitly by prepending the *module name*, e.g. `Swift.reverse()`:

```
extension String{

    func reverse()->String{
        var r = ""
        r.extend(Swift.reverse(self))
        return r
    }
}
```

---

Note that you can simplify the function slightly to

```
func reverse()->String{
    return String(Swift.reverse(self))
}
```

This works because `Swift.reverse()` returns an array, `Array` conforms to
`SequenceType`, and `String` has a constructor

```
init<S : SequenceType where Character == Character>(_ characters: S)
```

Comment: You just beat me in posting, but yes this is correct. Use the `Swift` namespace to unambiguously access the Swift Standard Library.